# De-registering a CSS file leaves it in the queue

Tags: css

I'm trying to de-register a CSS file that it is systematically add from a plugin. The CSS file it is useless in all pages.

So I have added a simple `wp_deregister_style` passing the name of the CSS class used for the registration purpose. As a matter of fact, the CSS file is no longer print, but looking at the `$wp_styles` variable I can still see the "item" in the queue array.

Any idea on how to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly and completely remove a style, you need to deregister([`wp_deregister_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style)) and dequeue([`wp_dequeue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style)) it. Dequeueing will remove the style from the array in the `$wp_styles` variable, deregistering the style will remove the stylesheet from being printed

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_deregister_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'genericons' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'genericons' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly! You can use [`wp_dequeue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) to dequeue an enqueued style. In fact, one might argue that it's better practice to *only* dequeue the style and not deregister it.